# Update view when object has been pushed into array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects, I have added a click handler to manual test pushing an item into that array, It does that successfully, but what it does not do is update the view based on this. Do I need to put the method in the `ngOnit`? What I have so far just makes the object appear not based the click handler.

Code so far would be:

```
public times = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Here and now",
      start: new Date("2021-01-27T09:00:00"),
      end: new Date("2021-01-27T09:30:00"),
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      title: "Here and now 2",
      start: new Date("2021-01-27T11:00:00"),
      end: new Date("2021-01-27T12:30:00"),
    }
  ];

public pushArray() {
    this.times.push({
      id: 3,
      title: "Again title",
      start: new Date("2021-02-02T10:00:00"),
      end: new Date("2021-02-02T12:30:00"),
    });
    console.log(this.times);
  }

  public addClickHandler() {
    this.pushArray();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pushArray();
  }
```

Binded to

```
<button class="mr-3" (click)="addClickHandler()">
Add </button>
```

But this works in the way of the object appearing already, not based on the click? I know putting the `this.pushArray()` into the ngOnit is not correct but just wanted to check it works and appears as it should if the user clicked and adde the item.

Comment: Are you binding the `events` object to the element in the view? 

What is your template like?

Comment: Can you provide the html

Comment: what is `events`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I have updated the question with the amends and the html.

Comment: He was previously pushing into an `events` array but now it's been updated to `times`. @Sole you need to bind the `times` array to an element in the HTML and that changes when an item is added to `times`

Comment: So this array is binded to an html element - Kendo Scheduler - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/scheduler/

I am pushing into the array for the data of the scheduler but the view is not updating based on just pushing the object into the array, If I Just put the method into the ngOnit then the additional object shows but not off the click handler

Comment: Can you show the interpolation in the html?

Comment: @yochanansheinberger Its based on this UI telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/scheduler

I know I need to update the UI after the array has been updated. So Was wondering is there an angular way to do it

Comment: Please share with us the full template

Comment: @Sole what if you add `this.times = [...this.times]` as the last row of `pushArray()` method?

Comment: In their case, they're using an events array and they're passing it as an input to the kendo component like this `<kendo-scheduler [kendoSchedulerBinding]="events">`, but in your case, the array is called times so it should be like this `<kendo-scheduler [kendoSchedulerBinding]="times">`. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @Benny So that does work? What is that method you mentioned? `this.times = [...this.times]`

Comment: @Sole did it help? Not sure I understand your comment

Comment: Yes that worked Benny, can you add as an answer, so i can accept it, also if you can explain what that line means?

Comment: @Sole great it worked. I posted an answer below with an explanation, to accept.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. I have removed `this.pushArray()` from `ngOnInit`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-trs7sk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the array's content changed, the view is not updated because the `times` array has not changed from Angular's change detection perspective, as the array is still in the same memory address (an array variable is a actually a reference). The solution is to reassign the array, thus changing its reference ("relocating" it to a different memory address) and trigger change detection. Like this:

```
public pushArray() {
    this.times.push({
      id: 3,
      title: "Again title",
      start: new Date("2021-02-02T10:00:00"),
      end: new Date("2021-02-02T12:30:00"),
    });
    this.times = [...this.times]; // <== this is the trigger
    console.log(this.times);
  }
```

For the same reason, in simple Typescript, you can do the following:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
a.push(5);  // <== you can add elements to const array because you don't change its address
```

But you can't do:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];  // <== the compiler will throw an error, because its address changes
```

and instead do:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];  // <== this will work
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks Benny.